# scheduleLocalNotification next fire date not working

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am trying to set repeat reminder... I am using this code:

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[task.reminder objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"AlertTime"] doubleValue]];

    localNotif.fireDate = date;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = [self textForAlertWithTask:task withIndex:i];
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Review";
    localNotif.soundName = [[defaults valueForKey:REMINDER_SOUND] stringByAppendingString:@".caf"];
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    if([task isRepeat] && [task.type isEqualToString:TYPE_TASK]){
        NSDate *fireDate = [Repeat getNextRepeatedReminder:task];
        if (!fireDate) return;
        localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
        int interval = [[task.recurrence valueForKey:RECURRENCE_UNIT] integerValue];
        if(interval == REPEAT_UNIT_DAY){
            //            DebugLog(@"Task is repeat - daily");
            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        }
        else if(interval == REPEAT_UNIT_WEEK){
            //            DebugLog(@"Task is repeat - weekly");
            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        }
        else if(interval == REPEAT_UNIT_MONTH){
            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
        }
        else if(interval == REPEAT_UNIT_YEAR){
            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;
        }
        else {
            //            DebugLog(@"error in setting a repeating alarm!");
        }
        //        DebugLog(@"Repeat - settings reminder to be - %d",interval);
    }

        DebugLog(@"scheduling the notification with title:%@\n%@",localNotif.alertBody, localNotif);
        localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

The log is:

```
{fire date = Monday, December 9, 2013, 7:20:50 PM Israel Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Jerusalem (GMT+02:00) offset 7200, repeat interval = NSDayCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday, December 9, 2013, 7:20:50 PM Israel Standard Time, user info = (null)}
```

As you can see the fire date and the next fire date is the same, how can it be ... ? the repeat interval is: "NSDayCalendarUnit" ...

Answer (score 3):

Your notification hasn't fired yet, therefore the next fire date *is* the initial fire date.

Answer (score 0):

Your `firedate` has too much information to work.

For example:

If your `localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;`

`firedate` only contain Hours minutes seconds.